# how to replace self in a class method?

Tags: python-3.x, class, self

I have a simple class coded as:

```
class test():
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def __add__(self, other):
        # returns a test object which is the sum of self and other
        return test(self.a + other.a)

    def double(self):
        print()
        print ('meanwhile inside test.double() ...')
        operand = test(self.a)     # a new test object similar to self
        print('    self:   ', self)
        print('    operand:', operand)
        self += operand
        print(' -> self:   ', self)

    def __str__(self):
        return '[> %r <]' % self.a

S1 = test(1)
S2 = test(2)
S = S1 + S2
print('sums do work : S = S1 + S2 =', S1, '+', S2, '=', S)

S.double()
print()
print('but S doubled =', S, '??')
```

The output is :

```
sums do work : S = S1 + S2 = [> 1 <] + [> 2 <] = [> 3 <]

meanwhile inside test.double() ...
    self:    [> 3 <]
    operand: [> 3 <]
 -> self:    [> 6 <]

but S doubled = [> 3 <] ??
```

So, how can I achieve this behaviour (i.e. that the self instance would be correctly updated when coming back from the called method) without having to copy all attributes (which in the real code are numerous and which would require each time an attribute is added to recheck the code to make sure the copying is complete)  ?

Answer (score 0):

`self` is just a variable, a reference to the instance. Binding it to another object only sets *that one reference*, not any other references to the instance. You can't replace other references. Either return the new instance and document that `double()` does this (so the caller has to rebind their reference), or update `self.a` in place.

Returning the new object:

```
class test():
    # ...

    def double(self):
        return self + self  # no need to create a new instance here

S = S.double()
```

or updating in-place:

```
class test():
    # ...

    def double(self):
        self.a *= 2
```

Which one you pick depends on wether or not you want `test()` instances to be mutable. An immutable object will always return a new instance for operations, a mutable object should apply the operation in-place.

You may want to read up about Python names, I recommend [Ned Batchelder's *Facts and myths about Python names and values*](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do would be to operate directly on the `a` attribute:

```
def double(self):
    self.a *= 2
```

This has the behavior of changing `self` in-place.

### Other solution using `__iadd__`

Using `self +=` will not currently update `self` in-place, as the `__add__` function (correctly) returns a new `test` object. If you for some reason wish to not operate directly on the `a` attribute in the `double` method, you can add the `__iadd__` method which gets called (instead of `__add__` if it exists) when using `+=`:

```
def __iadd__(self, other):
    self.a += other.a
def double(self):
    self += self
```

Additionally, I have left out the creation of `operarand`, as it is perfectly allowed for `other` to actually be the same as `self`.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion to use __iadd__ (in fact both yours and Martijn's answer below say more or less the same). I could define __add__ in terms of __iadd__ as def __add__(self,other): "r = self.deepcopy()" and then "r.__iadd__(other)" and finally "return r" . __iadd__ would now correctly update self in place and the example class would behave consistently ... or so I thought ... (see below)

Comment: You should avoid ever calling one of `__add__` and `__iadd__` from the other, as they are ment to be independent methods. It is best practice to simply work directly with the underlying data (here `self.a`) from within these so-called magic methods.

Answer (score 0):

So finally this code is working as expected

```
from copy import deepcopy

class test():
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def __iadd__(self, other):
        # this is the actual implementation of the sum of 2 objects
        self.a += other.a
        return self # <== required see comment below

    def __add__(self, other):
        # note: in the code I'm writing this is a relatively complex 
        # operation. So I would like to avoid to have it written in 
        # two places. So the actual implementation for the sum happens
        # in __iadd__
        r = deepcopy(self)
        r += other # <== implemented as r = r.__iadd__(other) behind the scenes
        return r   #     this is why the return self in __iadd__ is necessary !

    def double(self):
        print()
        print ('meanwhile inside test.double() ...')
        operand = test(self.a)     # a new test object similar to self
        print('    self:   ', self)
        print('    operand:', operand)
        self += operand
        print(' -> self:   ', self)

    def __str__(self):
        return '[> %r <]' % (self.a)


S1 = test(1)
S2 = test(2)
S = S1 + S2
print('sums do work : S = S1 + S2 =', S1, '+', S2, '=', S)

S.double()
print()
print('and S doubled =', S, '!!')
```

This seems to work as expected ...

```
sums do work : S = S1 + S2 = [> 1 <] + [> 2 <] = [> 3 <]

meanwhile inside test.double() ...
    self:    [> 3 <]
    operand: [> 3 <]
 -> self:    [> 6 <]

and S doubled = [> 6 <] !!
```

Note 1: `__iadd`__ needs to return self otherwise it will not work !

Note 2: I'm not sure I did this right (i.e. adding further questions to the set of answers) ... but I thought that if I added this to the question above the flow of the discussion would be difficult to follow.

Comment: but apparently this explained in one of the answers of question #1047034 : it is because (as I understand) x += y is called as  x = x.__iad__(y).